# Разница между определенно-личным и неполным

Tags: синтаксис

Я выхожу на прогулку. Смотрю - дорога перегружена автомобилями.

Каким является второе предложение - односоставным определенно-личным или двусоставным неполным?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Смотрю - дорога перегружена автомобилями.*-БСП. Первое предложение односоставное определённо-личное, второе двусоставное полное.

Общепринято, что неполным двусоставным считается предложение, если пропущенный член предложения приходится восстанавливать с помощью контекста или по ситуации. Здесь ничего восстанавливать не нужно, на подлежащее указывает форма сказуемого 1 лица, в данном случае это "я".

Если объединить 1 и 2 предложения в одно, тогда сказуемые будут рядом и будут восприниматься как однородные, вместо трёх будет 2 предложения: *Я выхожу на прогулку, смотрю - дорога перегружена автомобилями*.

Однако некоторые учёные предлагают все односоставные относить к неполным двусоставным, так что смотрите сами, какой точки зрения придерживаться. Если в школе - то точно *Смотрю* - **односоставное** предложение.